# generate sequence with squares, cubes and factorials of natural numbers

Tags: haskell

elements must be unique, how can I do it with Haskell

I tryed with *iterate* and *tuples* and it works but how can I check was this number in sequence or not (iterate thru all sequence is not optimal decision :).

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way round!

If you want to find out if a number is in the sequence you can either check it is a square, cube, or factorial, or you can generate all the numbers and check whether it is a member (which seems to be what you are proposing).

I'd approach this by writing some predicates, `isSquare`, `isCube` and `isFactorial`.

Comment: I don't want to check if it is in the sequence, I want to get the sequence

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since each sequence will be in ascending order, you can write a `merge` function to merge ascending lists (or use the one from the `ordlist` package).

```
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) =
    case compare x y of
        LT -> x : merge xs (y:ys)
        EQ -> x : merge xs ys
        GT -> y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

Then, you can define the final sequence by merging the other ones together:

```
squares = map (^2) [1..]
cubes = map (^3) [1..]
factorials = scanl1 (*) [1..]

foo = squares `merge` cubes `merge` factorials
```

```
> take 20 foo
[1,2,4,6,8,9,16,24,25,27,36,49,64,81,100,120,121,125,144,169]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
squares = map (^2) [1..]
cubes = map (^3) [1..]
factorials = scanl1 (*) [1..]

merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = x : merge xs ys
                    | x < y = x : merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys  

take 20 $ factorials `merge` squares `merge` cubes
--[1,2,4,6,8,9,16,24,25,27,36,49,64,81,100,120,121,125,144,169]
```